# How do I use an Vue app(without built) NPM as the site in a js app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, vuejs2, node-modules

My requirements, I need to call a Vue app that is in an NPM, from a simple js app. The NPM contains the entire Vue app site.

What would be the entry point on Vue app in the NPM?

I have tried different entry points but after published as an NPM I get errors like:

`function (exports, require, module, filename, dirname) { import Vue from 'vue'`

Is there are any way to access vue whole app in js app?

How would I tell the JS app to use this NPM as 'the' site?

Any other way also appreciate :)

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html (If you dont want to build the vue you can grep one of the files in the section "Direct <script> Include")

Comment: I have a veu js app it can be work stand alone but I need to use it in js app, suppose I have a cordova app and I have to use it like asked in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56945299/how-do-i-use-an-vue-app-npm-as-the-site-in-cordova